# Show that $S^{1} \vee S^{1}$ is a deformation retract of the space $Y=X \backslash \{x\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the space $X = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ that's equipped with the equivalence relation pictured below.

[image]

We let $x_{0} \in X/ \sim$ be the origin $x_{0}=[(0,0)]$. We have two paths defined $\gamma, \delta : [0,1]\longrightarrow X/\sim$ by $\gamma(t)=[(t,0)]$ and $\delta(t)=[(0,t)]$ for $t\in [0,1]$. So both paths start and end at the origin $x_{0}$. Let $[\gamma],[\delta] \in \pi_{1}(X, x_{0})$ be their path-homotopy classes.

(i) What are the formulas for the paths $\gamma \ast \delta$ and $\delta \ast \gamma$?

(ii) Show that the paths in (i) are path homotopic. Prove $[\gamma] \cdot [\delta] = [\delta] \cdot [\gamma]$ in $\pi_{1}(X, x_{0})$.

(iii) What is the fundamental group of $X$?

(iv) Prove that $S^{1} \vee S^{1}$ is a deformation retract for the space $Y=X\backslash \{x\}$ where $x$ is a point of $X$.

So for (i) I think the answer for $\gamma \ast \delta$ =
\begin{cases}
                                   \gamma(2t) & \text{if $0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$} \\
                                   \delta(2t-1) & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$} \\
  \end{cases}
but I'm not sure if its the same for  $\delta \ast \gamma$, maybe with the symbols swapped around??? Like is $\delta \ast \gamma$ =
\begin{cases}
                                   \delta(2t) & \text{if $0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$} \\
                                   \gamma(2t-1) & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$} \\
  \end{cases}? I'm not too sure about that...

for (ii) I'm not really sure how to go about proving either part. But I think maybe it should be easy to show $[\gamma] \cdot [\delta] = [\delta] \cdot [\gamma]$ in $\pi_{1}(X, x_{0})$ since when $[\gamma] \cdot [\delta]= [\gamma \ast \delta]$ which is an associative product?

(iii) I think the fundamental group of $X$ is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ since $X$ (I think) is just the torus with a point?

(iv) Going off the idea of (iii) if $X$ is homeomorphic to the torus then this question should just the matter of deforming the torus to $S^{1} \vee S^{1}$.

Am I on the right path for this? Can anyone give me any help for part (ii)?

Edit: Should it be that my $X$ is basically the Torus with $k$ points removed? SO then my fundamental group should be $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What is the equivalence relation?

Comment: @MathBug added picture now, would really like to know if I'm correct or not

Comment: I think it would help you to draw the paths in your picture and try to "push" one to the other. On the other hand, how do you have defined (in your course/class/book) $\gamma\ast\delta$? Usually it is defined as you say.

What results have you seen so far about this topic?

And why do you say that $X$ is a torus with some points removed? In your picture it is a torus without anything removed.

Comment: @MathBug We have $\gamma \ast \delta$ defined like that in our course. I'm just not confident in thinking that the reverse $\delta \ast \gamma$ would be the same? Sorry its only just hit me now that it is actually just a torus, dont know why i kept thinking it had points removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear but I think the space you are considering is the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with $(x,0)\sim(x,1), (0,y)\sim (1,y)$. The first edge identification gives a finite cylinder with two as edges and the second identifies the two circles to yield a torus. This is consistent with (ii), which is directing you to think that $\pi_1(X)$ is commutative.

Next, to see that $S^1 \vee S^1$ is a deformation retract of $X\setminus \{x_0\}$, we want to see that $S^1 \vee S^1$ is a deformation retract of a torus minus a point. We are free to choose any point on the torus. So go back to the square before the identifications and remove the center. Its easy to visualize a deformation from the square minus the center to the edges. Follow this deformation by the quotient map to get the deformation retract.

Comment: Ive added a picture now if that makes it any clearer

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought you meant.

Comment: As for (ii) , think about homotopies on the square before the identification. It shouldn't be too hard to write down a homotopy between $\gamma * \delta$ and the center diagonal and the same for $\delta  *  \gamma$, which will prove (ii)

Comment: Yeah I think I've got (ii) now. I'm now not sure about (iv) Ive got a diagram for and visually understand why it is true but I cant figure out a rigorous mathematical way of putting it

Comment: Let $q:[0,1]\times[0,1] \rightarrow X$ be the quotient map. Let $f_t$ be the radial deformation of $[0,1]\times [0,1] \setminus \{(1/2,1/2)\}$ to its boundary. Then $q \circ f _t$ is the deformation you want.